# scrapy can't crawl all links in a page

Tags: python, shell, xpath, scrapy

I am trying **scrapy** to crawl a ajax website http://play.google.com/store/apps/category/GAME/collection/topselling_new_free

I want to get all the links directing to each game.

I inspect the element of the page. And it looks like this:
[how the page looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDgb1.png)
 so I want to extract all links with the pattern /store/apps/details?id=

but when I ran commands in the shell, it returns nothing:
[shell command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3ric.png)

I've also tried //a/@href. didn't work out either but Don't know what is wrong going on....

- Now I can crawl first 120 links with starturl modified and 'formdata' added as someone told me but no more links after that.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: I am not familiar with scrapy, but have you tried [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)? It is a popular screen sraping libray I had success with in the past.

Comment: see view source, try to find those links, if you cant, those are written dynamically by javascript. you need something like phantomjs.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually an `ajax-post-request` which populates the data on that page. In scrapy shell, you won't get this, instead of inspect element check the `network` tab there you will find the request.

Make post request to `https://play.google.com/store/apps/category/GAME/collection/topselling_new_free?authuser=0` url with 
`formdata={'start':'0','num':'60','numChildren':'0','ipf':'1','xhr':'1'}`

Increment start by 60 on each request to get the paginated result.