# How to edit 'formdata' to crawl Ajax dynamic pages?

Tags: python, ajax, scrapy, web-crawler, html

Thanks to someone answering the question:
[scrapy can't crawl all links in a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35304470/scrapy-cant-crawl-all-links-in-a-page)

I've now successfully crawled an Ajax web page. However, only 120 links in that page can be crawled (540 in total) since I just simulated one request using `formdata={'start':'0','num':'60','numChildren':'0','ipf':'1','xhr':'1'}`.

I checked the 'network' and it shows I seem to need editing formdata more:

[image: [network]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OHbY.png)

I know there are many other ways out there to crawl ajax pages, but still having no clear idea after exploring various answers on the Internet.

Can someone offer ways to edit formdata` in my case? Or offer easier solutions?

Comment: for loop editing way for 'formdata' doesn't work. Still get an output of 120 records....

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this to change the formdata. If you need to change the `num` also, then you can edit the loop as per your requirement.

```
for i in range(0,10): 
    yield FormRequest(url="https://play.google.com/store/apps/category/GAME/collection/topselling_new_free?authuser=0", method="POST", formdata={'start':str(i+60),'num':'60','numChildren':'0','ipf':'1','xhr':'1'}, callback=self.data_parse)
```