# How to simulate xhr request using Scrapy when trying to crawl data from an ajax-based webstie?

Tags: python, ajax, scrapy, web-crawler, form-data

I am new to crawl the webpage using Scrapy and unfortunately chose a dynamic one to start...

I've successfully crawled part (120 links), thanks to someone helping me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35304470/scrapy-cant-crawl-all-links-in-a-page), but not links in [target website](https://play.google.com/store/apps/collection/topselling_new_free)

After doing some research, I know that crawling ajax web is nothing different from those simple ideas:

•open browser developer tools, network tab

•go to the target site

•click submit button and see what XHR request is going to the server

•simulate this XHR request in your spider

The last one sounds obscure to me though---How to simulate XHR request?

I've seen someone using 'headers' or 'formdata' and other parameters to simulate. Can't figure out what does that mean.

Here is part of my code:

```
class googleAppSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "googleApp"
allowed_domains = ['play.google.com']
start_urls = ['https://play.google.com/store/apps/category/GAME/collection/topselling_new_free?authuser=0']

def start_request(self,response):
    for i in range(0,10): 
        yield FormRequest(url="https://play.google.com/store/apps/category/GAME/collection/topselling_new_free?authuser=0", method="POST", formdata={'start':str(i+60),'num':'60','numChildren':'0','ipf':'1','xhr':'1','token':'m1VdlomIcpZYfkJT5dktVuqLw2k:1455483261011'}, callback=self.parse)

def parse(self,response):
    links = response.xpath("//a/@href").extract()
    crawledLinks = [ ]
    LinkPattern = re.compile("^/store/apps/details\?id=.")
    for link in links:
        if LinkPattern.match(link) and not link in crawledLinks:
            crawledLinks.append("http://play.google.com"+link+"#release")
    for link in crawledLinks:
            yield scrapy.Request(link, callback=self.parse_every_app)

def parse_every_app(self,response):
```

The start_request seems to not play any role here. If I delete them, the spider would still crawl the same amount of links.

I've worked on this problem for a week... Highly appreciate it if you could help me out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
class googleAppSpider(Spider):
    name = "googleApp"
    allowed_domains = ['play.google.com']
    start_urls = ['https://play.google.com/store/apps/category/GAME/collection/topselling_new_free?authuser=0']

    def parse(self,response):
        for i in range(0,10): 
            yield FormRequest(url="https://play.google.com/store/apps/category/GAME/collection/topselling_new_free?authuser=0", method="POST", formdata={'start':str(i*60),'num':'60','numChildren':'0','ipf':'1','xhr':'1','token':'m1VdlomIcpZYfkJT5dktVuqLw2k:1455483261011'}, callback=self.data_parse)

    def data_parse(self,response):
        item = googleAppItem()
        map = {}
        links = response.xpath("//a/@href").re(r'/store/apps/details.*')
        for l in links:
            if l not in map:
                map[l] = True
                item['url'] = l
                yield item
```

Crawl the spider using `scrapy crawl -o links.csv` or `scrapy crawl -o links.json` you'll get all the links in a csv file or a json file. To increase the number of pages to crawl, change the range of for loop.

Comment: loop doesn't work...for everytime it loops，it passes to the next parse function.

Comment: What does "doesn't works" means ? Aren't you getting all the links ?

Comment: still 120 links... not all links. interesting thing is if i delete that whole def function， i still get 120

Comment: If you will look closely, all the links after each request are completely different. You cannot get all the 540 links at once. This is what simulating xhr request means. Your browser sends a different xhr request whenever you scroll down. It doesn't get all the game links at once. This is exactly what the above code does. The loop is for each scroll down (each page).

Comment: Thanks... I ran the code exactly in cmd ( scrapy crawl ) and write the results into Json file. Then after I read the Json file into dataframe, I found out the length of that df is 120. It is how I find just crawl 120 links. Pls tell me what is wrong going on here...

Comment: Open the file in append mode. Let me do this with the help of items.

Comment: Is your problem solved or you need more clarification ?

Comment: Still unsolved... What do you mean by saying append mode?

Comment: What's your end goal ? Which links you want to store in the json file ?

Comment: My end goal is to follow all the app links in that page and then crawl and store every app information

Comment: According to your question, the above code will give you all the links.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But after storing urls into item, can I access them afterwards and thus yield request to each url to get app information in it?

Comment: items I really want to get is "app_name" "rating_star" and so forth... Sorry for making things complicated and confusing...

Comment: Please ask a new question if you want further clarifications. Also, before asking a new question try to attempt it on your own and come up with a code. Please accept the answer if it works for you.

Comment: Ok! Thanks a lot for your patience with a newbie

Comment: I will give a hint though. You can yield request and callback a new function for each url and you will get the required response of each app where you can scrape all other data.