# follow ajax contents in a webpage and keep crawling

Tags: python, ajax, xmlhttprequest, scrapy, web-crawler

What I want to do using Scrapy is by following all app links in the [webpage](https://play.google.com/store/apps/category/GAME/collection/topselling_new_free?) to crawl contents in every link.

Two steps generally:

1. get all links and extract every one of them
2. follow links to get the content

The problem is those links are ajax-based. So I used 'formdata' to simulate xhr request and store those links first in item.

I've done most code and now able to get all links thanks to people helping me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35472329/how-to-simulate-xhr-request-using-scrapy-when-trying-to-crawl-data-from-an-ajax/35473814#35473814)

However, when I try to follow links to get more content, everything goes wrong.

Here is my code.

```
def start_request(self,response):
    for i in range(0,10): 
        yield scrapy.Request(url="https://play.google.com/store/apps/category/GAME/collection/topselling_new_free?authuser=0", method="POST", formdata={'start':str(i*60),'num':'60','numChildren':'0','ipf':'1','xhr':'1','token':'m1VdlomIcpZYfkJT5dktVuqLw2k:1455483261011'}, callback=self.parse)

def parse(self,response):
    item = googleAppItem()   
    map = {}
    links = response.xpath('//a/@href').re(r'/store/apps/details.*')
    for l in links:
        if l not in map:
            map[l] = True
            item['url']=l
            l = "http://play.google.com"+str(l)
            request = scrapy.Request(l,callback=self.parse_every_app)
            request.meta['item'] = item
            return request
def parse_every_app(self,response):
```

Can somebody help me here?

This is screenshot of cmd when running codes goes wrong.
[image]

Comment: What is the error you're getting ?

Comment: I've added screenshot of cmd. And the output is just two duplicate records about app_name, developer things. No links at all...

Comment: The above error in the screenshot has no any relevance with the question you have asked. Show the full code of what you've tried so far. Also, have you tried to scrape any data in this fucntion `def parse_every_app(self,response):` ? Show the code.

Comment: Thanks! I've solved the problem. No mistakes in the code itself. Maybe the indent or something... Anyway, I finally made it. Thanks!